# Can one water hammer arrester serve multiple appliances?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-hammer

I have water hammer issue in my house. The cold-water pipe has a dedicated dead-end branch on the main water supply line and the water hammer can be prevent by flushing out the water and putting air in that dead-end branch. However, I didn't find same thing on my hot water pipe. My dishwasher, washing machine and faucets cause water hammer every time when shutting the hot water.

I purchased 2 water hammer arresters. I plan to choose one or two sink faucets that are close to the appliances and install the water hammer arrester on the hot water valve. Will that fix the whole house water hammer issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a great deal on the piping layout.

If there is a long branch to a device that slams valves shut quickly, the hammer arrestor needs to be out on that branch.
Ideally the arrestor should be located as close as possible to the quickly-closing valve. As such the arrestors that screw right in between the washer hoses and their  supply spigot are good for washing machines, for instance.

If there's a long line with short branches to devices, one arrestor at the end of that line *may* work.